# Azure CDN endpoint giving 502 bad gateway with https

Tags: c#, .net, http, azure, cdn

I just setup azure CDN endpoint. Pointed to my origin server. This works with http protocol. But the same files when i try https - it returns a 502 - bad gateway error. How do i troubleshoot and fix the problem?

A very similar setup works perfectly on another endpoint with HTTPs.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you may need to do is to serve your CDN assets over HTTPS. To do this you'll need to enable HTTPS within the Azure Portal**

if still not then:

You can't yet use your own domain/SSL certificate with Azure CDN although there is a big request for this on the Azure Feedback Site.

If you've created a CDN for an Azure Cloud Service (e.g. http://[yourapp].cloudapp.net/cdn/) it's important that you create a self-signed certificate for your Azure domain ([yourapp].cloudapp.net). If you're using Azure Virtual Machines this can be done through IIS.

This caught us out recently when we enabled HTTPS for an origin server that did have an SSL certificate but it was for our own custom domain and not the *.cloudapp.net one.

for details click on http://benfoster.io/blog/azure-cdn-https

Comment: I am serving my assets over HTTPS. I am using virtual machine and i have iis setup so i can access all my assets and url over HTTPS. But i dont get it. I have a site which works with azure cdn origin url pointed to https://beta.exampledomain.com/ but another subdomain does not work https://app.exampledomain.com/ Both are serving https content properly when you hit them directly.

Comment: Is your site is running directly from your VM and not via CDN other wise first, Please check you IIS setting for https ( 443 port binding ) given link will help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/06/18/bind-multiple-sites-on-same-ip-address-and-port-in-ssl.aspx

Comment: Yes - i have the site running directly on iis and the port bindings are all good. I can access HTTPS site with direct url with no problem. Problem is with CDN.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you ever get a resolution?